# DocFx does not generate documentation

Tags: c#, .net, documentation, javadoc, docfx

I'm trying to use DocFx to generate API documentation. I was under the impression that if I added `docfx.console` as a nuget package to my .NET project and built it, the documentation would be generated automatically. But that does not seem to be happening. It does generate some html files inside the `_sites` folder, but it doesn't convert my XML comments to a friendly doc format. What am I doing wrong? My project is ASP.NET MVC with C# (.NET 4.6.1).

Comment: docfx requires you to have Visual Studio (or at least the Build Tools) installed on that machine. Otherwise, it cannot generate any files. Such dependencies are not quite well documented, in case you missed. You'd better run its command line tool and learn its log files. Only when you are familiar with it, you can switch to the NuGet package.

Comment: @LexLi I do have Visual Studio installed. I have tried it on different computers with VS 2015 and VS 2017, but I got the same result in either case.

Comment: Check existing issues, or report yours as a new one https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/issues

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I solved by using command `docfx build [your project folder]` then `docfx serve [your project folder again]` on Developer Command.